# Setup iPhone Push Noification Server Proxy?

Tags: php, iphone, push, apple-push-notifications

Since my webhosting site blocks port 2195, which is required for communication with Apple's push notification server, our app push notifications are not working.

I've been looking all over for a solution:
1. Get a VPS (too expensive)
2. Use Urban Airship (push notification server)

Does anyone know, or have experience, developing some sort of proxy so I can have my php scripts go through a home server, which will then communicate with Apple's server?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: signed up with Lunarpages. Support communication through 2195

Answer (score 2):

Dreamhost VPS is just 15 bux. Cheap as heck if you ask me. I use it to send my notifications. Requires you to also have a shared account though, so really it comes out to a little more than 15.

I was on Lunarpages maybe 5 years ago or so and it went down A LOT. And they didn't let me run my own daemons unless I got a private server which was a lot there. I would've paid it if the service was better. Even if you don't think 15 is worth it for Dreamhost, their customer service is unlike anything I have experienced elsewhere. When you submit a ticket, they respond very quickly and I am very surprised how intelligent they are. They have always been able to fix my problems or answer my questions. Not just business hours either. I have submitted stuff at like 3 or 4 am and they respond within an hour or two sometimes.

Just some thoughts.